# Proper way to calculat time difference in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm calculating overtime duration of a worker. I've load data into datagridview. I've named column as startot(5th in position) and endot(6th in position). 
This is my code to calculate duration

```
 TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan();
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in attenViewGrid.Rows)
 {
     string start = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
     string end = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
     duration += DateTime.Parse(end).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(start));
  }
```

Now I'm facing problem when overtime start at 10:00 am to nextday 9:00am. What can be the best way to calculate over time duration.

Comment: You don't have the date part in those cells?

Comment: I've date part in those cells

Comment: What's the type of `row.Cells[5].Value`?

Comment: It is string @Enigmativity

Comment: @j_nug - Why then do `.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify date and time in your table cell, when you create a datetime object from parsing a time string it sets a fixed date.

Otherwise you could put a condition for a one-day increment:

```
 TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan();
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in attenViewGrid.Rows)
 {
     string start = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
     string end = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

     if(DateTime.Parse(end).Compare(DateTime.Parse(start)) < 0) 
         duration += Timespan.FromDays(1);

     duration += DateTime.Parse(end).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(start));
  }
```

Comment: I think condition isn't well. thank you for your reply

Comment: I added a "Compare" call which i think is the best way to compare dates